# Tableau How to show average of column

Tags: tableau-api

I have multiple column of survey answers from excel in tableau with the answers being 1,2,3,4,5. I want to show across the average for each column but in singular bar graph. For example row 1 would have a bar chart showing the average for that excel column, row 2 would show the average for its column etc. I would love the name of each excel column (Answer from survey) to be on the left side of the chart. However I can't figure it out since every time I drag the question into the row tab it starts showing (1-5) and doesn't just keep the average of the column. Thanks!

[image: Example of single ROw's answer]

[[image: Example of ExcelAnswer[1]]

Answer (score 1):

After replicating and trying what you described, my suggestions is to drag "Measure Values" (from Measure list on the sidebar) dropping in the "Columns" tray, and "Measure Names" on Rows.
Then use Measure Names as a filter, selecting the questions.

See Below:

[image]